# Creating a new PostgreSQL user in Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker

I need to create a new superuser for a PostgreSQL instance I am building in a `Docker` image. I can't seem to be able to create one, here's what I've tried so far...

**Try to create a new superuser with the "postgres" user**

```
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    sudo su - postgres &&\
    sudo psql -U postgres --command "CREATE USER pybossa WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'tester';" &&\
    createdb pybossa -O pybossa


> * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
>   ...done.
>psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

**"postgres" user by default has no password so I pass in `--no-password`**

```
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    sudo su - postgres &&\
    sudo psql -U postgres --no-password --command "CREATE USER pybossa WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'tester';" &&\
    createdb pybossa -O pybossa


> * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
>   ...done.
>psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

**So I pass in `-h localhost` to disable per auth**

```
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    sudo su - postgres &&\
    sudo psql -U postgres -h localhost --command "CREATE USER pybossa WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'tester';" &&\
    createdb pybossa -O pybossa

> * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
>   ...done.
>Password for user postgres:
>psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

**Finally, I try to use with `--no-password` and `-h localhost`**

```
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    sudo su - postgres &&\
    sudo psql -U postgres --no-password -h localhost --command "CREATE USER pybossa WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'tester';" &&\
    createdb pybossa -O pybossa

> * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
>   ...done.
>psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the default password `postgres`? I think if you don't run it with `sudo` then the default user is already `postgres` and then you won't need any of this.

Comment: See this: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4D958A35.8030501@hogranch.com

Comment: `sudo -u postgres psql --command "..."` ? [found this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/) uses `USER postgres` before `RUN`